# AngularJS: Controllers independent of $routeProvider are getting ReferenceError

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an angular app which has the following html structure

The content of `div[class="ng-view-wrap"]` is dependent of url but the `div[class="login-wrap"]` exists on every page and is handled by `rootCtrl`

The controllers which are activated by `$routeProvider` are working but `rootCtrl` is not working

As you can see I even used `"root"` in ng-controller(rootCtrl **as root**) and in the expression for loggedIn(**root**.loggedIn) so that the scope is referred to rootCtrl.

**Angular error:** Argument 'rootCtrl' is not a function, got undefined

**HTML:**

```
<div class="ng-view-wrap" ng-view=""></div>

<div class="login-wrap" ng-controller="rootCtrl as root">
    <div class="login">
        <p class="login-status">{{"Status: " + root.loggedIn }}</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**app.js:**

```
var mspBoard = angular
    .module('mspBoard',['ngRoute'])
    .config(function($routeProvider){
        $routeProvider
            .when('/',
                {
                    controller: 'boardCtrl',
                    templateUrl: 'js/views/board.html'
                })
            .when('/:project',
                {
                    controller: 'projectCtrl',
                    templateUrl: 'js/views/project.html'
                })
            .when('/:project/:topic',
                {
                    controller: 'topicCtrl',
                    templateUrl: 'js/views/topic.html'
                })
            .otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
    });
mspBoard.controller('rootCtrl',['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.loggedIn = true;
}]);
mspBoard.controller('boardCtrl',['$scope', function($scope){
    // Do Something
}]);
mspBoard.controller('projectCtrl',['$scope', function($scope){
    // Do Something
}]);
mspBoard.controller('topicCtrl',['$scope', function($scope){
    // Do Something
}]);
```

Comment: If you try other controller for example `boardCtrl` does it work?

Comment: Other question: where is definition of `ng-app`?

Comment: ng-app on html
boardCtrl works as i said its a controller related to $routeProvider

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing two types of syntax here `controller` and `controller as`.

In your `rootCtrl` add the line:

```
this.loggedIn = true;
```

If you are using `controller as` (which is the right approach IMO) then when you are defining the controller `this` will be treated as the scope for the controller without the need to inject `$scope`. The only reason you would need to inject `$scope` into a controller would be to take advantage of events ($broadcast, $emit, $on) or to trigger a digest loop ($digest, $apply).

I created this [**PLNKR**](http://plnkr.co/edit/ppwA7MG76JKCTgAoCQys?p=preview) as an example with your example code as a base.